# how can I have 2 dependent select?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

how can I process to create 2 dependent selects, what I need is for example when I select a country on the first select to have only cities that it belongs to this country on the second select

this is my first select :

```html
class CatParentCountries(models.Model):
    _name="cat.country"
    country = fields.Selection(
        selection=[
            ('country1', 'UAE'),
            ('country2', 'Canada'),          
        ], 
        required=True,       
    )
    
class CatCities(models.Model):
    _name="cat.cities"
    city=field.Char()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *dependent* selections?

Comment: need more description about what you want to achieve.code is working fine but not understand Qn.?

Comment: see the edits plz

Comment: is your cat.country and cat.city not have a relation field?

Answer (score 0):

There are models available in odoo for Country, State. You can refer it From...

- **Sales => Configurations => Contacts =>
  Localization => Country**
- **Sales => Configurations => Contacts =>
  Localization => Fed. State**

Like the same you can achieve it by defining relations between these two models. In state model there must be Many2one (state_id). The same way you can define city model.

```
Class res_city(models.Model):
    _name = 'res.city'
    name = fields.Char('City')
    state_id = fields.Many2one('res.country.state', 'State')
```

Now you need to use city model's many2one anywhere you want.
Xml file should looks like

```
<field name="country_id" />
<field name="state_id" domain="[('country'_id','=',country_id)]" />
<field name="city_id" domain="[('state'_id','=',state_id)]" />
```

> The things can be done easily just by specifying in domain in field,.
>   but that's only possible if you have define relation in model.

Comment: country , state was just an example to explain what I need. I used Many2one but now I have a Problem is that when i chose the second select the first select value disapear

Comment: Can you please post exact model structure with issue and requirement ?

Comment: here the exact model structure [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031421/why-the-value-of-the-first-select-disappear]